# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null XMLHttpRequest JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access YouTube v3 API and getting user info using access token. I am getting full JSON in response with all details with i want but this error also come with that.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('GET',
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&' +
'access_token=' + access_token);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
  var channel = xhr.response.items[0]; **// This is the error line**
  document.getElementById('token').value = user.Zi.access_token;
};
xhr.send(null);
```

console log

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null
at XMLHttpRequest.LoadData.xhr.onreadystatechange
LoadData.xhr.onreadystatechange @ main.js:93
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
LoadData @ main.js:101
setSigninStatus @ main.js:65
updateSigninStatus @ main.js:114
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:267
c.port1.onmessage @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:153
```

Comment: Please add this code `console.log(xhr.response)`, and add the result.

Comment: Also note the warning in the documentation about `responseType`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not waiting for the response to be complete, and you're not checking for success. You need to check `readyState === 4` to know whether the response is complete, and `status === 200` to know if the request was successful:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('GET',
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&' +
'access_token=' + access_token);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    // Request is complete -- did it work?
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // Success
      var channel = xhr.response.items[0];
      document.getElementById('token').value = user.Zi.access_token;
    } else {
      // Failure, handle/display error
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

---

Side note: You don't appear to be using `channel` after retrieving it. Instead, you're using some `user` variable that the code closes over. I assume your real code will use `channel`. :-)

Side note 2: In modern environments, you might use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. But if you do, beware of the footgun in the API that I describe [on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) (TL;DR - be sure to check `ok` before calling any of the body load methods).

Comment: Thanks its work, Its look like i was access the values before get full response, Thanks